# Postback page minimized the browser - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page that have few dropdowns and when the dropdown item changed it refresh the page and reloads.

so now i am writing script against that page and i have noticed that whenever my scripts select the text from the dropdown my browser get minimized.

my questions, is there any setting to make sure my browser is maximized while running the script?

Here is the code that SelectText from the dropdown:

```
     public void SelectText(By locator, string txt)
     {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(locator);
            SelectElement selectelement = new SelectElement(element);
            selectelement.SelectByText(txt);    
     }
```

I am using

```
IE 8
Selenium 2 WebDriver 
C#
```

Comment: It being minimised **shouldnt** cause much of an issue, although I've not had this happen to me so I may very well be wrong, does it cause a problem? There is a method to explicitly maximise the window: `Driver.Manage().Window.Maximise();`

Comment: I strongly suspect that the browser is actually being dropped to the bottom of the Z-order, not minimized. That is to say, it's being pushed to the bottom of the stack of open windows on your desktop. If you have other applications running, and they're running maximized, it can appear as though IE has been minimized, but it really isn't. There are certain actions that are known to cause IE to behave this way, but no one has been able to figure out why yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the browser is actually being dropped to the bottom of the Z-order, not minimized. That is to say, it's being pushed to the bottom of the stack of open windows on your desktop. If you have other applications running, and they're running maximized, it can appear as though IE has been minimized, but it really isn't. There are certain actions that are known to cause IE to behave this way, but no one has been able to figure out why yet.

Maximizing the IE window won't solve the problem. Nevertheless, you can maximize the IE window using

```
// WARNING! Untested code written from memory
// without the benefit of an IDE. Not guaranteed
// to be syntactically correct. 
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```